# ¿Existe otra forma de insertar datos en Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

estoy realizando un programa de pruebas automatizadas en **Selenium** el caso es que necesito insertar datos que se encuentran en un **charAT()** al ponerlo en el **sendKeys()** me sale error.
¿Existe otra forma de insertar datos en Selenium, o estoy haciendo algo mal?

Aquí el código:

```
String imagen = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"cimg1\"]/img")).getAttribute ("src");
WebElement numeroone = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"main\"]/form/div[2]/input"));

char onetime = imagen.charAt(35);
numeroone.sendKeys(onetime);
```

Comment: SendKeys es un metodo que necesita recibir un CharSequence y tu le esas pasando un Char para que funcione tu codigo necesitass convertir tu variable ontime a un String, lo mas simple seria que concateneras la variable onetime y un string vacio ejemplo : numeroone.sendKeys(onetime+"");

Comment: Hola @JGarnica gracias por tu comentario amigo! 
¿Me podrías indicar como debo hacer eso? Soy algo nuevo en esto de RPA y no tengo una base. Te lo agradecería un montón colega!

Comment: @JGarnica ¡LISTO AMIGO! Realmente te lo agradezco un montón por tu ayuda, me salvaste la nota. Mil gracias nuevamente, funciono tal como lo necesitaba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas convetir tu Char a un String para que tu codigo funcione en el metodo sendKeys

```
String imagen = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"cimg1\"]/img")).getAttribute ("src");
WebElement numeroone = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"main\"]/form/div[2]/input"));

String onetime = imagen.charAt(35)+"";
numeroone.sendKeys(onetime);
```